# Call variable names (w/ number) using for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get values from `req.body.answerX` using `for` loop instead coding each of them.

I've stored values e.g. into "`answer1`, `answer2`" etc.

This was my attempt:

```
  for( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

        console.log(req.body.answer[i]);

   }
```

That gives me following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have `req.body.answerX` at the top then `req.body.answer` in your loop, which is it?

Comment: @vapurrmaid X at the top was to indicate a random number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update from

```
console.log(req.body.answer[i]);
```

to

```
console.log(req.body["answer" + i]);
```

For reference, [Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, just close votes and (if appropriate) comments.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I started to look into way more complicated solutions.